# How can I set deadline as the I/O scheduler for USB Flash devices by using udev rules?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, io, udev

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Udev rule is not working](https://superuser.com/questions/481748/udev-rule-is-not-working)

I have set CFQ as the default I/O scheduler. I often get bad performance when I write data into a Flash device. This is resolved if I use deadline as the I/O scheduler for USB Flash devices. I can't always change the scheduler manually, right? I think writing udev rules is a good idea.

Can someone please write rules for me? I want:

1. When I plug in a USB device, detect the type of the device.
2. If it is a portable USB hard disk, do nothing (I think if a device has more than one partitions, it always a portable hard disk.
3. If it is a USB Flash device, set deadline as it's scheduler.

Comment: Have you read the udev manual? Have you tried the udev monitor? Have you tried creating a rule? What is the exact actual practical problem that you are experiencing? We can't see your hardware, thus not write rules.

Comment: Actually, I read lots of article about USB & udev. But they just try to detect new device of /dev/sdx, no matter a USB device or something else.

Comment: Ok. I read a lots of f**king manuals. And I know how to write the rules now. But udev does not seem to see my rules (any rule), It not working at all. Please see the question http://superuser.com/questions/481748/udev-rule-is-not-working.

Comment: If you were to use `udevadm monitr` like the manuals tell you, you wouldn't put `??` into your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put the shell script `scheduler4usb` into `$PATH` (e.g: `/usr/bin`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./script device scheduler

# If your are using util-linux 2.22, you must change this line to:
# fdisk /dev/$1 -l 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -q "doesn't contain a valid partition table"
#
fdisk /dev/$1 -l 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -q "This doesn't look like a partition table"

# If this device has a partition table.
if (($?==0)); then 
    echo $2 > /sys/block/$1/queue/scheduler
fi

exit
```

**Don't forget to `chmod +x scheduler4usb` to your script!**

Then, write the rule into `/etc/udev/rules.d/91-change-schduler.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/scheduler4usb %k deadline"
```

Comment: Instead of ```RUN+="some_script"``` you can directly modify the sysfs attributes: ```..., ATTR{queue/scheduler}="deadline"```

Comment: @hurikhan77: is the list of supported sysfs attributes documented somewhere? I was surprised to find that this would work at all when `udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/sdX` doesn't list these attributes.

Comment: You can look at the directory `/sys/block/sda` - `ATTR{}` will actually just write to the files therein.